# nginx doesn't serve "/" path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a domain example.com which is registered and working.

I am now trying redirect all requests to `example.com` and `www.example.com` to a specific port.

the `default` config in sites-enabled looks like this:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

     location / {
         return 301 https://example.com:8081/;
     }
}
```

the above config does not work (when accessing `example.com` in the browser, i get infinite loading)

While when using this config, `example.com/test` works.

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

     location /test {
         return 301 https://example.com:8081/;
     }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question to see the complete configuration.

Comment: why not using proxy_pass instead return?